# How to find coefficient of the line equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression

I am trying to get the coefficient's a,b,c from the line equation "ax+by+c", without using NumPy or any libraries.
I tried string parsing but it is not successful, please help me I am new to python.

Comment: Hmm... A little unclear. Do you want to parse a, b and c out of the string? If so, are they in symbolic form (like ``a``, ``b``, and ``c``) or they have some values (like ``1``, ``2``, and ``3``)?

Comment: yes, a,b,c are variables.

Comment: What are your inputs and expected outputs? What cases do you have to handle?

Comment: input:1x-2y+8 and expected output would be: a=1,b=-2,c=8

Answer (score 2):

I case you want to parse a string with numbers for a, b and c, then the following python example shows you how to do this:

```
import re

p = re.compile('([\d*\.\d+|\d+]+)x\+([\d*\.\d+|\d+]+)y\+([\d*\.\d+|\d+]+)')
m = p.match("1.2x+3y+4.5")

print("a=%s" % m.group(1))
print("b=%s" % m.group(2))
print("c=%s" % m.group(3))
```

or without using regular expressions:

```
e = "1.2x-3y+4.5"

p=['']
for c in e: # loop through all characters
    if c in ['.', '-'] or c.isdigit(): # if it's dot, minus or digit append it to the last parameter
      p[len(p) - 1] += c
    else: # otherwise create a new parameter 
        if len(p[len(p) - 1]) != 0: # when there isn't one yet
            p.append('') # append new parameter

print("a=%s" % p[0])
print("b=%s" % p[1])
print("c=%s" % p[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping..but,Is there any other way to solve this,with out using re?

Comment: I've added another example which doesn't use regular expressions.

Comment: thanks, it helped, but when the input is -1x+2y-0.5, outputs are a =1,b=2,c=0.5 but it should be a= -1,b = 2,c= - 0.5.please help me if you know how to solve this :)

Comment: I have added the '-' sign to the valid number symbols